# What are the meanings of these transcript ids?

Tags: proteins, transcriptome, rna, phylogenetics, nomenclature

I have three types of transcripts for *Rosa chinensis* "Old Blush" homozygous genome v2.0 from GDR genome browser.

```
RcHm_v2.0_CPg0501991
RcHm_v2.0_Chr0c12g0499591  or RcHm_v2.0_Chr1g0313011
RcHm_v2.0_MTg0498341
```

Does anyone know what this means. At least "CPg" and "Mtg". I know "Chr" means chromosome. And there is "1" at each and every transcript. But it is not separated using anything, like people do to mention the transcript number. I will be grateful if someone can help.
Thank you.